# addLink position being ignored

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, xml

I am adding some links to my `footer_links` block, however I want them to be the last links added.

In my local.xml file I have:

```
<reference name="footer_links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" ifconfig="mymodule_options/style/fb_link">
        <label><![CDATA[<img title="Facebook" src="/media/wysiwyg/fb.png">]]></label>
        <url helper="mymodule/getFbLink" />
        <title>Facebook</title>
        <prepare/>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>10</position>
        <liParams>
            <class>left</class>
        </liParams>
        <aParams>
            <target>_blank</target>
        </aParams>
    </action>
    <!-- repeat above for other social media links -->
</reference>
```

I have set the `position` attribute as a variety of values, but it is still appearing at the top of the list of links.

Some Googling suggests that the parameters need to be in the same order as the function call `addLink`. The signature for this function is:

```
public function addLink($label, $url='', $title='', $prepare=false, $urlParams=array(), $position=null, $liParams=null, $aParams=null, $beforeText='', $afterText='')
```

As you can see, the `position` is in the correct place.

How do I set the position of my link to the bottom of the list via xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had entered the above into the `page.xml` layout file. There are two solutions:

1) in every `.xml` file that is adding a link to `footer_links` add a lower `position` attribute so my links appeared further down the list

2) create a local.xml file and add the above links there. As local.xml is loaded LAST, the links were added LAST. At this point, `position` kicked in and I could place my links anywhere in the list.

I opted for option 2.